# Apache: Testing against multiple module

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

We can use Apache's `IfModule` directive to test presence or absence of a specific module. Apache also allows nested `IfModule` directives which can be used to test multiple modules, in other words we can implement logic `AND`.

Is it also possible to implement logic `OR`? For example is it possible to use something *similar* to this:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c OR sapi_apache2.c>
    # Some directives
</IfModule>
```

Instead of this:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    # Some directives
</IfModule>
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
    # Absolutely same directives with mod_php.c
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

While it's not perfect, you could put the directives you want into a separate file, and then `Include` it in the relevant locations.  I don't believe there's a way to do a logical OR in a single `IfModule` statement.

Comment: Although it's not perfect, it's definitely a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    # Some directives
</IfModule>
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        # Absolutely same directives with mod_php.c
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

> `<IfModule>` sections are nest-able, which can be used to implement
>   simple multiple-module tests.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifmodule

Not sure since when it's available.

Comment: This can only be used for AND tests. Orginal post is about OR tests.